What's the impact of being async on getBy*() and queryBy*() queries in WebdriverIO Testing Library?
I'm trying to get at the exact difference in getBy*() vs queryBy*() vs findBy*() in WebdriverIO Testing Library.
I'm asking because the docs describe all of them as async ("All queries are async..."), and thus I wonder how that changes the behavior particularly of getBy*() and queryBy*(), which are normally synchronous. For example, do they wait for some time for elements to appear or resolve immediately?
For example, if I call:
const myElement = await browser.getByText('Lorem ipsum');

what exactly is different than when calling:
const myElement2 = await browser.findByText('Dolor sit');

I've read:

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about
https://testing-library.com/docs/webdriverio-testing-library/intro/
What's the difference between getByText vs findByText vs queryByText in testing-library?

